# How come I don't see a close button on Electrical Engineering SE site?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I am a member of a fair number of sites on the Stack Exchange network.

On most of them, I see a "vote to close" button on posts.

I have 900+ rep on the EE SE, but don't see a close button. That seems odd. Why don't they have one?

Comment: This looks like a FAQ (not the limits, but the multiple accounts), but [I failed to find it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=close+faq+rep).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electrical Engineering does have a close vote button. You just don't have enough reputation there to have close-voting privileges yet though, so you don't see the button. You need [3000](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) points before it becomes visible.

You can still flag the question and put it in the close vote queue that way.

Comment: Oh wow. A higher bar than I'm used to for close VOTING. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Duncan same bar should apply on SO, but maybe that's too long ago? :) Here's a list that explains the differences: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/369802

Comment: Tinkeringbell, thanks for that link. Very informative.

Comment: It might be that I've had 3000+ rep on SO for a long, looooong time and mis-remember when I got the close vote privledge. (Love the name BTW)

Comment: @DuncanC note that with 900+ rep on EE.SE, you can actually [vote to close, but only on your own questions (250 rep)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)